# How to remove attached grid line from SVG file for putting in latex?

Tags: svg, grids

I have a ".svg" file that has a grid line in the background. Is there any way that I can remove the background from the SVG file?? the file is in this [LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1klVLwkGReIw_izBnUQshRj-BTZR5gWUl/view)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange! I flagged this question as off-topic as it has nothing to do with TeX, LaTeX or any related program. It is simply about modifying an image file.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as it has nothing to do with TeX, LaTeX or any related program. It is simply about modifying an image file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do that in LaTeX, but you should probably be able to edit the `.svg` file itself. It might not even be that bad (esp. of course if you have something like Adobe Illustrator), since a `.svg` file is just a bunch of almost-human-readable text. (You can see this if you open the file with a text editor). Below the figure without the grid (i.e. the part of it I assume you wanted to remove), and after that the original file. I removed the grid with Adobe Illustrator, so there might be some other small changes in the file as well. Hopefully with this you can identify the part of the actual code that accounts for the grid and remove manually however you please. For how to include the `.svg` afterwards there's plenty of questions and answers on here already. All the best!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 330 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 330 200;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#CCCCCC;}
    .st1{display:none;fill:#32313F;enable-background:new    ;}
    .st2{font-family:'HelveticaNeue-Thin';}
    .st3{font-size:13.5px;}
    .st4{fill:#32313F;}
    .st5{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);}
    .st6{fill:none;stroke:#009988;stroke-width:2;}
    .st7{fill:none;stroke:#EE3377;stroke-width:2;}
    .st8{opacity:0.2;}
    .st9{clip-path:url(#SVGID_4_);}
</style>
<g>
    <g>
        <g>
            <g>
                <g>
                    <line class="st0" x1="48.9" y1="177" x2="43.9" y2="177"/>
                    <line class="st0" x1="48.9" y1="151.7" x2="43.9" y2="151.7"/>
                    <line class="st0" x1="48.9" y1="126.4" x2="43.9" y2="126.4"/>
                    <line class="st0" x1="48.9" y1="101.1" x2="43.9" y2="101.1"/>
                    <line class="st0" x1="48.9" y1="75.9" x2="43.9" y2="75.9"/>
                    <line class="st0" x1="48.9" y1="50.6" x2="43.9" y2="50.6"/>
                    <line class="st0" x1="48.9" y1="25.3" x2="43.9" y2="25.3"/>
                    <line class="st0" x1="48.9" y1="0" x2="43.9" y2="0"/>
                </g>
                <g transform="translate(38.875, 0)">
                    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -23.5169 181.042)" class="st1 st2 st3">-0.5</text>
                    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -7.506 155.7574)" class="st4 st2 st3">0</text>
                    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -18.765 130.4728)" class="st4 st2 st3">0.5</text>
                    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -7.506 105.1883)" class="st4 st2 st3">1</text>
                    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -18.765 79.9037)" class="st4 st2 st3">1.5</text>
                    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -7.506 54.6191)" class="st4 st2 st3">2</text>
                    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -18.765 29.3346)" class="st4 st2 st3">2.5</text>
                    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -7.506 4.05)" class="st1 st2 st3">3</text>
                </g>
                <line class="st0" x1="48.9" y1="0" x2="48.9" y2="177"/>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g>
            <defs>
                <rect id="SVGID_1_" x="48" width="281" height="176"/>
            </defs>
            <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
                <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
            </clipPath>
            <g transform="translate(48, 0)" class="st5">
                <g>
                    <g>
                        <g>
                            <g>
                                <g>
                                    <path class="st6" d="M23.4,34.8l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1
                                        l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1
                                        l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2
                                        l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.4
                                        l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.7
                                        l2.3,1.2l2.3,1.3l2.3,1.3l2.3,1.1l2.3,0.9l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.5l2.3,1.1l2.3,1.4l2.3,1.5l2.3,1.5l2.3,1.2l2.3,0.5l2.3,1.2
                                        l2.3,1.6l2.3,2.4l2.3,1.7l2.3,0.8l2.3,0.2l2.3,2.3l2.3,2.7l2.3,2.3l2.3,1.6l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.6l2.3,1.3l2.3-1.9
                                        l2.3,2.1l2.3,2.5L253,89l2.3,1.3l2.3,2.4"/>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <path class="st7" d="M23.4,34.2l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1
                                        l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.4
                                        l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.8l2.3,0.8l2.3,1l2.3,1.2l2.3,1.2l2.3,1.2
                                        l2.3,1.3l2.3,1.5l2.3,1.6l2.3,1.8l2.3,1.7l2.3,2.2l2.3,1.8l2.3,2.6l2.3,1.8l2.3,1.8l2.3,1.1l2.3,2.9l2.3,1.7l2.3-0.4
                                        l2.3-1.6l2.3,4.2L157,81l2.3,1.6l2.3,1.9l2.3,1l2.3-1.6l2.3,4.5L171,93l2.3,2.6l2.3,1.2l2.3-1.2l2.3,3.2l2.3,3.1l2.3,2.1
                                        l2.3,1.9l2.3,1.4l2.3,0.9l2.3,1.5l2.3,1.4l2.3,0.9l2.3-0.3l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.8l2.3,0.1l2.3,1l2.3,1.5l2.3,1.1l2.3,1.2l2.3,1.1
                                        l2.3,1l2.3,0.9l2.3,0.8l2.3,0.7l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.7l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.3
                                        l2.3,0.3"/>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g class="st8">
                        <g>
                            <g>
                                <g>
                                    <path class="st6" d="M23.4,34.8l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1
                                        l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1
                                        l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2
                                        l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.5
                                        l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.6l2.3-0.1l2.3,0.6l2.3,1l2.3,2.1
                                        l2.3,1.4l2.3,1.3l2.3,0.9l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.3l2.3,2.1l2.3,1.9l2.3,1.7l2.3,1.5l2.3,0.6l2.3-0.5l2.3,2.3l2.3,2.2
                                        l2.3,3.5l2.3,0.6l2.3-0.4l2.3-0.8l2.3,5.6l2.3,3.1l2.3,1.8l2.3,0.7l2.3-1.2l2.3,0.7l2.3,0.6l2.3,2.3l2.3-6.8l2.3,8.2
                                        l2.3,3.2l2.3,1l2.3,0.4l2.3,3.9"/>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <path class="st7" d="M23.4,34.2l2.3,1l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1
                                        l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.4
                                        l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.7l2.3,0.7l2.3,0.9l2.3,0.9l2.3,1.3l2.3,1.5l2.3,1.3
                                        l2.3,1.3l2.3,1.3l2.3,1.8l2.3,1.7l2.3,2.3l2.3,1.4l2.3,3l2.3,1.3l2.3,3.8l2.3,0.6l2.3,1.8l2.3,0.2l2.3,5.5l2.3,0l2.3-3.5
                                        l2.3-3.4l2.3,12.8l2.3,5.2l2.3-2.9l2.3,2.3L164,87l2.3-5.4l2.3,13.6l2.3,4.6l2.3-0.2l2.3-1l2.3-4.7l2.3,9.6l2.3,3.1
                                        l2.3,0.6l2.3,1.6l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.1l2.3,2.4l2.3,1.3l2.3,0l2.3-2l2.3,1.9l2.3,1l2.3-0.8l2.3,2.4l2.3,2.2l2.3,0.5l2.3,1.4
                                        l2.3,1l2.3,0.7l2.3,0.8l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.9l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.7
                                        l2.3-0.1l2.3,0.3"/>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g>
            <defs>
                <rect id="SVGID_3_" x="48" y="176" width="281" height="22"/>
            </defs>
            <clipPath id="SVGID_4_">
                <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
            </clipPath>
            <g transform="translate(48, 176)" class="st9">
                <g>
                    <g>
                        <line class="st0" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="23.4" y1="0" x2="23.4" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="46.9" y1="0" x2="46.9" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="70.3" y1="0" x2="70.3" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="93.7" y1="0" x2="93.7" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="117.1" y1="0" x2="117.1" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="140.6" y1="0" x2="140.6" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="164" y1="0" x2="164" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="187.4" y1="0" x2="187.4" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="210.8" y1="0" x2="210.8" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="234.3" y1="0" x2="234.3" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="257.7" y1="0" x2="257.7" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="281.1" y1="0" x2="281.1" y2="5"/>
                    </g>
                    <g transform="translate(0, 8)">
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -9.8819 12.825)" class="st1 st2 st3">-10</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 19.6741 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">0</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 39.3482 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">10</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 62.7753 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">20</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 86.2023 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">30</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 109.6294 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">40</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 133.0565 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">50</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 156.4836 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">60</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 179.9107 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">70</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 203.3378 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">80</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 226.7648 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">90</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 246.4389 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">100</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 269.866 12.825)" class="st1 st2 st3">110</text>
                    </g>
                    <line class="st0" x1="0" y1="0" x2="281.1" y2="0"/>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

[image: screenshot]

Original file (code formatted by Adobe Illustrator):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 330 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 330 200;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#CCCCCC;}
    .st1{display:none;fill:#32313F;enable-background:new    ;}
    .st2{font-family:'HelveticaNeue-Thin';}
    .st3{font-size:13.5px;}
    .st4{fill:#32313F;}
    .st5{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);}
    .st6{opacity:0.25;fill:none;stroke:#3C3C3C;enable-background:new    ;}
    .st7{fill:none;stroke:#999999;stroke-width:1.5;}
    .st8{fill:none;stroke:#009988;stroke-width:2;}
    .st9{fill:none;stroke:#EE3377;stroke-width:2;}
    .st10{opacity:0.2;}
    .st11{clip-path:url(#SVGID_4_);}
</style>
<g>
    <g>
        <g>
            <g>
                <g>
                    <line class="st0" x1="48.9" y1="177" x2="43.9" y2="177"/>
                    <line class="st0" x1="48.9" y1="151.7" x2="43.9" y2="151.7"/>
                    <line class="st0" x1="48.9" y1="126.4" x2="43.9" y2="126.4"/>
                    <line class="st0" x1="48.9" y1="101.1" x2="43.9" y2="101.1"/>
                    <line class="st0" x1="48.9" y1="75.9" x2="43.9" y2="75.9"/>
                    <line class="st0" x1="48.9" y1="50.6" x2="43.9" y2="50.6"/>
                    <line class="st0" x1="48.9" y1="25.3" x2="43.9" y2="25.3"/>
                    <line class="st0" x1="48.9" y1="0" x2="43.9" y2="0"/>
                </g>
                <g transform="translate(38.875, 0)">
                    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -23.5169 181.042)" class="st1 st2 st3">-0.5</text>
                    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -7.506 155.7574)" class="st4 st2 st3">0</text>
                    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -18.765 130.4728)" class="st4 st2 st3">0.5</text>
                    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -7.506 105.1883)" class="st4 st2 st3">1</text>
                    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -18.765 79.9037)" class="st4 st2 st3">1.5</text>
                    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -7.506 54.6191)" class="st4 st2 st3">2</text>
                    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -18.765 29.3346)" class="st4 st2 st3">2.5</text>
                    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -7.506 4.05)" class="st1 st2 st3">3</text>
                </g>
                <line class="st0" x1="48.9" y1="0" x2="48.9" y2="177"/>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g>
            <defs>
                <rect id="SVGID_1_" x="48" width="281" height="176"/>
            </defs>
            <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
                <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
            </clipPath>
            <g transform="translate(48, 0)" class="st5">
                <g>
                    <g>
                        <g>
                            <line class="st6" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="177"/>
                            <line class="st6" x1="23.4" y1="0" x2="23.4" y2="177"/>
                            <line class="st6" x1="46.9" y1="0" x2="46.9" y2="177"/>
                            <line class="st6" x1="70.3" y1="0" x2="70.3" y2="177"/>
                            <line class="st6" x1="93.7" y1="0" x2="93.7" y2="177"/>
                            <line class="st6" x1="117.1" y1="0" x2="117.1" y2="177"/>
                            <line class="st6" x1="140.6" y1="0" x2="140.6" y2="177"/>
                            <line class="st6" x1="164" y1="0" x2="164" y2="177"/>
                            <line class="st6" x1="187.4" y1="0" x2="187.4" y2="177"/>
                            <line class="st6" x1="210.8" y1="0" x2="210.8" y2="177"/>
                            <line class="st6" x1="234.3" y1="0" x2="234.3" y2="177"/>
                            <line class="st6" x1="257.7" y1="0" x2="257.7" y2="177"/>
                            <line class="st6" x1="281.1" y1="0" x2="281.1" y2="177"/>
                        </g>
                        <g>
                            <line class="st6" x1="0" y1="177" x2="281.1" y2="177"/>
                            <line class="st6" x1="0" y1="151.7" x2="281.1" y2="151.7"/>
                            <line class="st6" x1="0" y1="126.4" x2="281.1" y2="126.4"/>
                            <line class="st6" x1="0" y1="101.1" x2="281.1" y2="101.1"/>
                            <line class="st6" x1="0" y1="75.9" x2="281.1" y2="75.9"/>
                            <line class="st6" x1="0" y1="50.6" x2="281.1" y2="50.6"/>
                            <line class="st6" x1="0" y1="25.3" x2="281.1" y2="25.3"/>
                            <line class="st6" x1="0" y1="0" x2="281.1" y2="0"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g>
                    <g>
                        <line class="st7" x1="0" y1="151.7" x2="281.1" y2="151.7"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g>
                    <g>
                        <line class="st7" x1="23.4" y1="0" x2="23.4" y2="177"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g>
                    <g>
                        <g>
                            <g>
                                <g>
                                    <path class="st8" d="M23.4,34.8l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1
                                        l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1
                                        l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2
                                        l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.4
                                        l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.7
                                        l2.3,1.2l2.3,1.3l2.3,1.3l2.3,1.1l2.3,0.9l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.5l2.3,1.1l2.3,1.4l2.3,1.5l2.3,1.5l2.3,1.2l2.3,0.5l2.3,1.2
                                        l2.3,1.6l2.3,2.4l2.3,1.7l2.3,0.8l2.3,0.2l2.3,2.3l2.3,2.7l2.3,2.3l2.3,1.6l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.6l2.3,1.3l2.3-1.9
                                        l2.3,2.1l2.3,2.5L253,89l2.3,1.3l2.3,2.4"/>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <path class="st9" d="M23.4,34.2l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1
                                        l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.4
                                        l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.8l2.3,0.8l2.3,1l2.3,1.2l2.3,1.2l2.3,1.2
                                        l2.3,1.3l2.3,1.5l2.3,1.6l2.3,1.8l2.3,1.7l2.3,2.2l2.3,1.8l2.3,2.6l2.3,1.8l2.3,1.8l2.3,1.1l2.3,2.9l2.3,1.7l2.3-0.4
                                        l2.3-1.6l2.3,4.2L157,81l2.3,1.6l2.3,1.9l2.3,1l2.3-1.6l2.3,4.5L171,93l2.3,2.6l2.3,1.2l2.3-1.2l2.3,3.2l2.3,3.1l2.3,2.1
                                        l2.3,1.9l2.3,1.4l2.3,0.9l2.3,1.5l2.3,1.4l2.3,0.9l2.3-0.3l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.8l2.3,0.1l2.3,1l2.3,1.5l2.3,1.1l2.3,1.2l2.3,1.1
                                        l2.3,1l2.3,0.9l2.3,0.8l2.3,0.7l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.7l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.3
                                        l2.3,0.3"/>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g class="st10">
                        <g>
                            <g>
                                <g>
                                    <path class="st8" d="M23.4,34.8l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1
                                        l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1
                                        l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2
                                        l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.5
                                        l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.6l2.3-0.1l2.3,0.6l2.3,1l2.3,2.1
                                        l2.3,1.4l2.3,1.3l2.3,0.9l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.3l2.3,2.1l2.3,1.9l2.3,1.7l2.3,1.5l2.3,0.6l2.3-0.5l2.3,2.3l2.3,2.2
                                        l2.3,3.5l2.3,0.6l2.3-0.4l2.3-0.8l2.3,5.6l2.3,3.1l2.3,1.8l2.3,0.7l2.3-1.2l2.3,0.7l2.3,0.6l2.3,2.3l2.3-6.8l2.3,8.2
                                        l2.3,3.2l2.3,1l2.3,0.4l2.3,3.9"/>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <path class="st9" d="M23.4,34.2l2.3,1l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.1
                                        l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.4
                                        l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.4l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.7l2.3,0.7l2.3,0.9l2.3,0.9l2.3,1.3l2.3,1.5l2.3,1.3
                                        l2.3,1.3l2.3,1.3l2.3,1.8l2.3,1.7l2.3,2.3l2.3,1.4l2.3,3l2.3,1.3l2.3,3.8l2.3,0.6l2.3,1.8l2.3,0.2l2.3,5.5l2.3,0l2.3-3.5
                                        l2.3-3.4l2.3,12.8l2.3,5.2l2.3-2.9l2.3,2.3L164,87l2.3-5.4l2.3,13.6l2.3,4.6l2.3-0.2l2.3-1l2.3-4.7l2.3,9.6l2.3,3.1
                                        l2.3,0.6l2.3,1.6l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.1l2.3,2.4l2.3,1.3l2.3,0l2.3-2l2.3,1.9l2.3,1l2.3-0.8l2.3,2.4l2.3,2.2l2.3,0.5l2.3,1.4
                                        l2.3,1l2.3,0.7l2.3,0.8l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.5l2.3,0.3l2.3,0.9l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.2l2.3,0.6l2.3,0.1l2.3,0.7
                                        l2.3-0.1l2.3,0.3"/>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g>
            <defs>
                <rect id="SVGID_3_" x="48" y="176" width="281" height="22"/>
            </defs>
            <clipPath id="SVGID_4_">
                <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
            </clipPath>
            <g transform="translate(48, 176)" class="st11">
                <g>
                    <g>
                        <line class="st0" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="23.4" y1="0" x2="23.4" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="46.9" y1="0" x2="46.9" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="70.3" y1="0" x2="70.3" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="93.7" y1="0" x2="93.7" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="117.1" y1="0" x2="117.1" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="140.6" y1="0" x2="140.6" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="164" y1="0" x2="164" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="187.4" y1="0" x2="187.4" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="210.8" y1="0" x2="210.8" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="234.3" y1="0" x2="234.3" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="257.7" y1="0" x2="257.7" y2="5"/>
                        <line class="st0" x1="281.1" y1="0" x2="281.1" y2="5"/>
                    </g>
                    <g transform="translate(0, 8)">
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -9.8819 12.825)" class="st1 st2 st3">-10</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 19.6741 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">0</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 39.3482 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">10</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 62.7753 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">20</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 86.2023 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">30</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 109.6294 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">40</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 133.0565 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">50</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 156.4836 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">60</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 179.9107 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">70</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 203.3378 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">80</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 226.7648 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">90</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 246.4389 12.825)" class="st4 st2 st3">100</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 269.866 12.825)" class="st1 st2 st3">110</text>
                    </g>
                    <line class="st0" x1="0" y1="0" x2="281.1" y2="0"/>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```